# How to send information from Arduino?

Tags: arduino-uno, communication

I plan to make an air quality monitoring system that uses Arduino uno, but I can't decide how I will be able to distribute the air condition and harmful gas concentration info and have it available to other people.

Aside from using a GSM module to text individual persons and making a new website to chart the data from the Arduino, what else can I use to receive information that my Arduino sensed to people's smartphones/computers wirelessly?

Comment: Use a nodeMCU: faster, more memory and WiFi included. You can even run a little web server from it.

Answer (score 1):

> what else can I use to receive information that my Arduino sensed to people's smartphones/computers wirelessly?

take a different route. get the information to a pc (or to a server through a pc) and you have much more flexibility.

there are many ways to get that information to a pc, like serial, spi, i2c, acquisition cards, wired / wireless, ....

Answer (score 0):

There is a Wi-Fi module named "ESP-01" (which uses the ESP8266 microcontroller) and it comes ready to be used with Arduino. But better than that, I think, is that you can program it directly via Arduino's IDE if you flash it with [NodeMCU's firmware](http://randomnerdtutorials.com/flashing-nodemcu-firmware-on-the-esp8266-using-windows/). You can also use a NodeMCU instead of Arduino, but ESP-01 has the advantage of being much, much cheaper.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pair of ESP8266 WiFi Transceiver modules (one as the client and the other as the server).

There are a few guides to [getting started with the ESP8266](http://randomnerdtutorials.com/getting-started-with-esp8266-wifi-transceiver-review/) out there, which generally contain some helpful tips.

I also found this fairly straightforward [ESP8266 – Wireless Weather Station with Data Logging to Excel](http://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp8266-wireless-weather-station-with-data-logging-to-excel/) project which illustrates the principle of using a pair of ESP8266 modules as client and server.

Answer (score 0):

Others suggest ESP8266, but I think it's now outdated, there's a new and improved version of it available named ESP32, it's better in basically every way (faster, more RAM, ROM etc.), not that much more expensive and can still be programmed using the Arduino IDE, that means programming it just as simple as programming an ESP8266.

Disclaimer: ESP32 Arduino core is still under development, some less frequently used features might be experimental or missing.